# Matching div height to parents , on window resize and load

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I am able to match a child container to the parents height on page load, however my issue is getting it to match the parents height when resizing the window, here is my code so far:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="ocg-hero" class="container">
 <div class="row">

  <div class="large-6 columns heroContent"> </div>
  <div class="large-6 columns heroGraphic" > </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

**Script**:

```
function heroImageResize (){
    var heroHeight = $("#ocg-hero .row").height(),
        heroGraphicHeight = $(".heroGraphic").height();

        $(".heroGraphic").css("height",heroHeight);
};

heroImageResize();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Oh sweet, foundation. You could use `$(window).resize(heroImageResize);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For both handlers:

```
$(window).on('load resize',heroImageResize);
```

Comment: Do you want to trigger it on window load, or on document ready?

Comment: onload for sure e.g if element contains images, no?

Comment: Yes, but that can also constitute a significant delay. A wise developer will specify dimensions for all images anyway.

Comment: ya true, but with some kind of loader animation should not be a real problem

Comment: @Blazemonger  following your last part of comment, i'm totally agree

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has an event for resizing, you can use that for recalculating your height.

http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){   
   $(window).resize(heroImageResize);
});
```

as you it on page load also -

```
$(function(){  
  $(window).resize(heroImageResize).resize();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use resize http://api.jquery.com/resize/

```
$(window).resize( heroImageResize);
$(document).ready(function(){ $(window).resize(); /*triggers it*/  })
```